# RSpec view tests can't find partials that are in base namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

EDIT:

I found that if I insert `view.lookup_context.prefixes = %w[base]` before `render`, the test knows the proper path. Is this the best/proper way of solving this?

---

I put all my partials in a base folder, and all the controller that have access to those partials inherit from the `base_controller` this all works great, but the generated view tests can't find the partials that are in the base folder.

Here is the error:

```
Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       Missing partial /admin_menu, circuits/admin_menu with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
         * "/Users/Mac/Folder/ProjectName/app/views"
```

How do I tell my view test where to look for the partials?

for completeness, here is the spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "circuits/index" do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:circuits, [
      stub_model(Circuit,
        :name => "Name",
        :description => "MyText"
      ),
      stub_model(Circuit,
        :name => "Name",
        :description => "MyText"
      )
    ])
  end

  it "renders a list of circuits" do
    view.lookup_context.prefixes = %w[base application]
    render
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Name".to_s, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "MyText".to_s, :count => 2
  end
end
```

Comment: What's the full path to to your `admin_menu` template, and how are you referencing it inside of `circuits/index`?

Comment: full path is `app/views/base/_admin_menu.html.erb`. In circuits/index it's referenced with `<%= render 'admin_menu' %>`, which works fine because the circuits_controller inherits from the `base_controller`, which inherits from the `application_controller`

Comment: Experienced this error with `grape`+`jbuilder`+rspec view specs when rendering partials. Your edit/answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
<%= render 'base/admin_menu' %>
```

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar issue when using partial inheritance to add themes feature to my app. For Rails 4 it was a bit different than in the edited answer - I had to add this in my view specs:

```
before do
  view.lookup_context.view_paths.push 'app/views/themes/light'
end
```

where the `themes/light` folder contained some partials specific to the light theme.

Comment: Probably want to use `unshift` instead of `push` so that in the case of same partial path, the added path has precedence

Comment: Thank you so much, that's the one!